# Where can I find a Magento mod/addon/plugin that can do a Flyer/Online Brochure

Tags: helper

I'm looking to create an online flyer or (page visual) catalog, or brochure that can be put onto one of my CMS pages in Magento, I'd like the ability for the viewer to click next/back for different pages.

Exactly how grocery stores do their online flyers....

If anyone knows a Magento addon that can do this, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know 3 options, non Magento all of them but easy to add to a CMS page by pasting the code in the WYSIWYG editor.

https://prezi.com

http://flippingbook.com/

http://issuu.com/